# Django not updating objects completely; cache or index?

Tags: django, sqlite, orm

I inserted through SQL (`manage.py dbshell`) a handful of records.  I then went to view the records in the Django admin interface.  All of the records appeared, as expected.

However, any queries via Django (not direct SQL), did not return the records.  Only after I went to a record through the admin interface, and clicked `Save` did the record appear in the query.

I'm new to Django, but after repeated searching and reading Django documentation, I did not find an answer.  Any idea what is going on, and what can be done to make the `SQL INSERT` statements appear in queries without visiting each record to `Save` it through the admin interface?

Comment: What do you mean with "However, any queries via Django (not direct SQL), did not return the records." ? Can you post an example ?

Comment: Please forgive me, as I'm new to Django.  I can see the records when I use SQL in dbshell to query, and through the admin interface.  But regular code, that is not part of the admin interface, such as listing all records that meet some date criteria, are not returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have to declare the transaction "[dirty](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#transactions-and-raw-sql)":

```
from django.db import transaction
transaction.set_dirty()
```

Comment: In dbshell?  Can you give me more information on how Django marks dirty transactions?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this works. You can try in Django shell (`manage.py shell`). Have you tried to restart the web server?